# Addition-Subtraction of Numbers Within String

Tags: code-golf, string

Take a string as an input, and perform addition/subtraction of all the digits in the string and output the sum of those operations as the result.

### Rules

- The digits in the string are read from left to right
- If a digit (n) is odd, perform addition with the next digit (n + n1)
- If a digit (n) is even, perform subtraction with the next digit (n - n1)
- If you've reached the last digit in the string, perform the operation with the first digit in the string
- Output will be the sum of all the resulting values
- If there is only one digit in the string, perform the operation with itself (n+n or n-n)
- If there are no digits in the string, output is 0

### Example

```
Input: r5e6o9mm!/3708dvc    
Process: (5+6) + (6-9) + (9+3) + (3+7) + (7+0) + (0-8) + (8-5)
Output: 32
```

### Notes

- Either function or full program is accepted
- Maximum input length would depend on your language's limit for a string input
- No restrictions on character input, but only half-width digits count towards the output
- Fewest bytes wins

Comment: Yup, mistakes were made on the original post. Edited now to make it clearer. Thanks for pointing them out, they should be all match with the instructions now.

Comment: A couple more examples would be good too

Comment: I'd recommend to add a test case ending with an odd digit.

Comment: Suggested testcase: `""`, `"0"`, `"1"`

Comment: Can we take input as an array of characters instead of a string? (Julia makes a distinction between those two.)

Comment: @sundar The [current consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/58563) is that a string is defined as a sequence of characters. My understanding is that arrays of characters are therefore allowed by default even if your language has a native _string_ type.

Comment: @NoirAntares "_If a digit (n) is even or 0, ..._" - you could say just "If a digit (n) is even, ..."

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17 15</s> 12 bytes

```
fØDV€ḂT‘ịƲSḤ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//ZsOYRFbigqzhuIJU4oCY4buLxrJT4bik////J3I1ZTZvOW1tIS8zNzA4ZHZjJw)

[Try test cases.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/t8AyXsEdNax7uaAp51DDj4e7uY5uCH@5Y8v/h7i2H24ES//@rq6sXmaaa5Vvm5irqG5sbWKSUJXOZpJhwmaaacpnr6upyqVmocSUmJXMZchkAFQMA)

The program keeps only the digits that follow an odd digit then computes twice the sum.

```
fØDV€ḂT‘ịƲSḤ   
f                   Remove anything that isn't...
 ØD                 a digit.
   V€               Cast each digit to an integer
         Ʋ          Monad:
     Ḃ              Parity of each digit.
      T             Indices of truthy elements (odd digits).
       ‘            Increment.
        ị           Index into list of digits.
                    Wraps to beginning and if there are no digits this returns 0.
          S         Sum.
           Ḥ        Double.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>47</s> <s>43</s> <s>40</s> 31 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{+/(1_x,*x)*2*2!x^:(x-:48)^!10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1pbX8MwvkJHq0JTy0jLSLEizkqjQtfKxEIzTtHQoNZB30pDqcg01SzfMjdXUd/Y3MAipSxZyVopMSnZEEilpKYZAamKyiolzf//AQ)

**Explanation:**

Remove everything from string that isn't a number (whilst also converting), modulo 2, multiply by 2, multiply with x rotated by 1, and sum up.

```
{+/(1_x,*x)*2*2!x^:(x-:48)^!10} / solution
{                             } / lambda taking implicit x
                           !10  / range 0..10
                          ^     / except
                   (     )      / do this together
                    x-:48       / subtract 48 from x (type fudging char ascii value -> ints), save back into x
                x^:             / x except right, and save back to x
              2!                / modulo 2
            2*                  / multiply by 2
           *                    / multiply by
   (      )                     / do this together
        *x                      / first element of x
       ,                        / append to
      x                         / x
    1_                          / drop first (ie rotate everything by 1)
 +/                             / sum, add (+) over (/)
```

**Naive solution:**

Remove everything from string that isn't a number (whilst also converting), take 2-item sliding window, figure out whether they are odd or even, apply add/subtract as appropriate, then sum up.

```
{+/((-;+)2!x).'2':(1+#x)#x^:(x-:48)^!10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1pbX0ND11pb00ixQlNP3UjdSsNQW7lCU7kizkqjQtfKxEIzTtHQoNZB30pDqcg01SzfMjdXUd/Y3MAipSxZyVopMSnZEEilpKYZAamKyiolzf//AQ)

**Notes:**

- **-4 bytes** thanks to @ngn due to a smarter way of filtering the input
- **-3 bytes** by using sliding window rather than reshape
- **-9 bytes** porting ngn's solution (non-naive approach)

Comment: `x:48!x@&x in,/$!10` -> `x^:(x-:48)^!10`

Comment: I wrote the solution in q/kdb+ then ported to oK... might be able to squeeze a few more bytes out of this yet!

Comment: I posted a [separate answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168039/addition-subtraction-of-numbers-within-string/168063#168063) in ngn/k, feel free to bring in ideas from there. I think oK will end up being the shortest, as my parser is rubbish at the moment - it doesn't parse modified assignment properly. By the way, I wasn't aware of `':` as "sliding window" - interesting.

Comment: You seem to be well familiar with k. If you ever feel like discussing vector programming stuff with like-minded people or just watching the rest of us argue - we've got [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard). Most of the banter is about APL, but k and J are on-topic too.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 86 bytes

```python
k=[int(a)for a in input()if'/'<a<':']
print sum(a-(-1)**a*b for a,b in zip(k,k[1:]+k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9s2OjOvRCNRMy2/SCFRITMPiApKSzQ0M9PU9dVtEm3UrdRjuQqKgIoUiktzNRJ1NXQNNbW0ErWSFMBadJJAmqoyCzSydbKjDa1itbM1Nf//VyoyTTXLt8zNVdQ3NjewSClLVgIA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> 9 bytes

Saves 1 byte over the naive method by utilizing [dylnan's parity trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168042/47066)
Saved 3 bytes thanks to *Mr. Xcoder*

```
þDÁ€ÉÏSO·
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8D6Xw42PmtYc7jzcH@x/aPv//0WmqWb5lrm5ivrG5gYWKWXJAA)

**Explanation**

```
þ              # push only digits of input
 D             # duplicate
  Á            # rotate right
   €É          # get the parity of each
     Ï         # keep only true items
      SO       # calculate digit-sum
        ·      # double
```

Comment: Hmm, would `þÀIþ€ÉÏSO·`, `þÀDÁ€ÉÏSO·`, `þÀ¹þ€ÉÏSO·` or `þÀsþ€ÉÏSO·` pass all test cases for -2 bytes?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Ah, yes. Nice! We can even do `þDÁ€ÉÏSO·` for -3 :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 41 bytes

```perl6
{2*sum rotate($!=.comb(/\d/))Z*(@$! X%2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCoMgFADQ9/sVCk00UEfLag/BPmOMvZgaDGaGWhBjvz53zuriuyv@QGRGIyqfpk6bRzFknR2t8ChM8BOVTysZe9T0VmF0PzXsWwSZRdJHicp14eo9lpf@PNjdQGtbUE5BzzkHMhDQkwH1C2t@hSUVvvwB)

Uses the same logic as [dylnan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168042/76162). This sums only digits that follow an odd number and then multiplies by 2.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>18</s>  17 bytes

```
t4Y2m)!Ut1YSof)sE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L/EJNIoV1MxtMQwMjg/TbPY9b9LZkmkn21dbMV/9SLTVLN8y9xcRX1jcwOLlLJkdS51QyNjE1MgnVicBiKTkg0rKtW5/BL9AA)

*(-1 byte thanks to Luis Mendo/Giuseppe/both!)*

Explanation:

```
     % Implicit input
 t   % duplicate input
     % stack: ['r5e6o9mm!/3708dvc' 'r5e6o9mm!/3708dvc']
 4Y2 % push inbuilt literal, characters '0':'9'
     % stack: ['r5e6o9mm!/3708dvc' 'r5e6o9mm!/3708dvc' '0123456789']
 m)  % extract only characters from input that belong to '0':'9'
     % stack: ['5693708']
 !U  % transpose and convert each value from string to number
     % stack: [5 6 9 3 7 0 8]
 t   % duplicate that
 1YS % circular shift by 1
     % stack: [[5 6 9 3 7 0 8] [8 5 6 9 3 7 0]]
 o   % parity check - 1 for odd, 0 for even
     % stack: [[5 6 9 3 7 0 8] [0 1 0 1 1 1 0]]
 f   % find non-zero value indices in last array
     % stack: [[5 6 9 3 7 0 8] [2 4 5 6]]
 )   % index at those places in the first array
 s   % sum
 E   % multiply by 2
     % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

The basic idea is that numbers that follow even numbers can be ignored, while those that follow odd numbers are doubled - and the final result is the sum of those doubled values.

I didn't think `f` after the parity check `o` would be necessary, but for some reason MATL doesn't see the array of 0's and 1's that result from the `o` as a logical array, instead takes them as numerical indices and indexes into positions `1` and `end`.

Comment: I think you can use `!U` instead of `48-`. The transpose doesn't seem to do any harm here. `o` for `double` input is just `mod(...,2)`,  so the output is `double`. Nice `NaN` input trick! If that's meant to solve the extraneous output in STDOUT, Dennis [had an idea](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45481684#45481684) and will probably fix that soon

Comment: `!U` instead of `48-`

Comment: @LuisMendo welp, you beat me to the punch!

Comment: @Giuseppe :-D :-D

Comment: Thank you both, edited. @LuisMendo When does `o` give a logical array output then - or does it not? (I must confess I've never really looked into MATLAB's numeric type system.) And yeah, I thought `NaN` would make for a nice sentinel since it's unlikely to be actual input anywhere, but good to know it won't be needed for much longer!

Comment: Yes, `o` always gives `double` output (unless I am missing some edge case)

Comment: @sundar Dennis already [deployed the fix](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45513968#45513968), so `NaN` [won't be needed](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L/EJNIoV1MxtMQwMjg/TbPY9b9LZkmkn21dbMV/9SLTVLN8y9xcRX1jcwOLlLJkdS51QyNjE1MgnVicBiKTkg0rKtUB) anymore

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>80</s> <s>78</s> 76 bytes

```
($d="$args"-split'\D*'-ne'')+$d[0]|?{$p-match'[13579]';$p=$_}|%{$s+=2*$_};$s
```

-2 bytes thanks [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) with Retina solution

-2 bytes thanks [AdmBorkBork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42963/admborkbork)

Test script:

```
$f = {
($d="$args"-split'\D*'-ne'')+$d[0]|?{$p-match'[13579]';$p=$_}|%{$s+=2*$_};$s
}

&$f 'r5e6o9mm!/3708dvc'
```

### Explanation

First of all: it sould add 2*n if previous digit is odd, and 0 if a previous digit is even.

```
($d="$args"-split'\D*'-ne'')+ # let $d is array contains digits only, each element is a digit
$d[0]|                        # apend first digit to the end of the array
?{                            # where for each digit
    $p-match'[13579]'         # predicate is 'previous digit is odd' (it is false on the first iteration because $p is null)
    $p=$_                     # let previous digit is current
}|
%{                            # for each digit matched to the predicate
    $s+=2*$_                  # add current digit multiply 2 to $s. 
}
$s                            # return sum
```

---

### Extra, 99 bytes

Inspired by @Neil. Regex match digits with 'previous digit is odd' only. `Matches` is an [automatic variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables).

```
param($d)$d+($d-match'\d')+$Matches[0]|sls '(?<=[13579]\D*)\d'-a|%{$_.Matches.Value|%{$s+=2*$_}};$s
```

Comment: Save a byte swapping `|?{$_}` for `-ne''`and another by moving `$d="$args"-split'\D*'-ne''` into parens like `($d="$args"-split'\D*'-ne'')+$d[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 33 bytes

```
{+/(1_x,*x)*2*2!x:-48+x^x^,/$!10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcnbCoIwGADg@56iDS88soMdbP@jiKapizAVhsS/xF59Yd198PXJeB@d02qJmC@uGIcYhDKUBFVyyCIssYyZRwRf3awWL7cfo/QeoZp68CtdP56AYMEExbqbc2qO3Wm6DANh6Zln7auhkMpim/rWCAp/t52WFPjPaN8b3Rc)

`{` `}` is a function with argument `x`

`!10` is the list `0 1 ... 9`

`$` convert to strings

`,/` concatenate

`x^` means `x` without what's on the right

`x^x^` means `x` intersected with what's on the right, i.e. keep only the digits from `x`

`-48+` subtract `48`, which is the ASCII code of `"0"`

`x:` assign to `x`

`2!` mod 2

`2*` multiplied by 2

`1_x,*x` is one drop of: `x` followed by the first of `x`; i.e. `x` rotated to the left by one step

`+/` sum

Answer (score 2):

## Japt (v2.0a0), <s>25</s> 19 bytes

<sup>*-6 bytes thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974).*</sup>

```
kè\D
íÈ°*2*Y°u}Ué)x
```

Try it [here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=a+hcRArtyLAqMipZsHV9VekpeA==&input=WyJyIiwiNSIsImUiLCI2IiwibyIsIjkiLCJtIiwibSIsIiEiLCIvIiwiMyIsIjciLCIwIiwiOCIsImQiLCJ2IiwiYyJd).

It works with no digits this time! Input is a list of characters.

Comment: [19 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ZlxkCu1V6Sl4yCtbLVlZXWdYdQ==&input=InI1ZTZvOW1tIS8zNzA4ZHZjIg==), including switching to Japt v2. Not happy with the array in the `x`function, though. Ping me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34018/japt) if you've any questions.

Comment: Wait, just noticed that this won't work at all if the input doesn't contain any digits.

Comment: Also, where's the source for v2.0a0, @Shaggy? I can't find it in the repo.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/blob/master/src/japt-interpreter.js) is v1 and [this](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/blob/master/src/japt.js) is v2.

Comment: In case you missed it in chat, I got this down to [12 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=a1xEIOTPKjIqsFh2&input=InI1ZTZvOW1tIS8zNzA4ZHZjIgoteAo=) for you.

Comment: Ah, nuts! Just realised that that one will fail if there's only 1 digit in the input. There's a 16 byte version in chat, though, that *does* work under all conditions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 37 bytes

```
(\d).*
$&$1
L$`(?<=[13579]\D*).
2**
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/XyMmRVNPi0tFTcWQy0clQcPexjba0NjU3DI2xkVLU4/LSEuLK/7//yLTVLN8y9xcRX1jcwOLlLJkAA) Explanation:

```
(\d).*
$&$1
```

Append a duplicate of the first digit.

```
L$`(?<=[13579]\D*).
```

Match anything whose first previous digit is odd.

```
2**
```

Convert all the matches to unary and double them. (Non-digits are treated as zero.)

```
_
```

Take the sum. If there were no matches, then this produces zero as required.

The best I could do in Retina 0.8.2 was 44 bytes:

```
[^\d]

(.).*
$&$1
(?<![13579]).

.
$*
.
..
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/Oi4mJZaLS0NPU0@LS0VNxZBLw95GMdrQ2NTcMlZTj4tLj0tFC0joAdH//0WmqWb5lrm5ivrG5gYWKWXJAA) Explanation:

```
[^\d]
```

Delete non-digits.

```
(.).*
$&$1
```

Append a copy of the first digit.

```
(?<![13579]).
```

Delete digits that do not follow an odd digit.

```
.
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
.
..
```

Double them.

```
.
```

Take the sum.

Comment: I'm afraid the result will be incorrect if the last digit is not odd

Comment: @mazzy When you say the last digit, do you mean before or after copying the first digit to the end?

Comment: 'to the end'. the step 'Append a duplicate of the first digit' is copying to the end? ok. cool. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters.

```javascript
s=>s.map(c=>1/c?r+=p*(p=c*2&2,n=n||c,c):0,n=p=r=0)|r+p*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcpBDsIgEEDRvbewCwO0UqzWqsnUgxgXZEqNpsAETFfcHfUA6u4n7z/0rCOGOz3Xzg8mj5Aj9FFaTQyh39R4DiWQYAQomlVTOXApYYX8pN5NEEDxFEoSLqN30U9GTv7GRnaRUhahNXt/tHZZbzt1GGYsrpwv/o3dj3H3DdoP5Bc)

#### Commented

```javascript
s =>                     // given the input array s[]
  s.map(c =>             // for each character c in s[]:
    1 / c ?              //   if c is a digit:
      r +=               //     update r:
        p * (            //       p = either 0 or 2 (always 0 on the 1st iteration)
          p = c * 2 & 2, //       p = 0 if c is even, 2 if c is odd
          n = n || c,    //       if n is still equal to 0 (as an integer), set it to c
          c              //       compute p * c
        )                //     add the result to r
    :                    //   else:
      0,                 //     do nothing
    n = p = r = 0        //   n = first digit, p = previous digit, r = result
  )                      // end of map()
  | r + p * n            // compute the last operation with the 1st digit and add it to r
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 58 bytes

```r
function(x,y=strtoi(x[x%in%0:9]))sum(c(y[-1],y[1])*y%%2*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tdLRCoIwFAbge5/CiDEnRnOSZeCTiBe1FLxQQ2fMp19/KeGFN6UNvpsd@Hc4Z43JY5N3lVRFXTna6@NWNaouHJ1oUlSEn6OUsbYrHen0yc5PvT7xU@b2hAhXMJPjnjbUowfIIIQaIihHG9hDAEfgcIIbPEBSxuytnel7JlV2swNhvXM1agPUfz2TXD7E@kviZmLHbsXKsZ9uPXoBAddxiPLbpyax4RC7RrMz3fL/DOH1mxavbboyblnmCQ)

- using [dylnan's parity trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168042/41725)
- -8 bytes accepting vector of characters instead of strings
- -3 byte thanks to @Giuseppe

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##jc1BC4IwGMbxu59iEcNNlOZWpoEfoHs38bDmBh6cITO2T7@0LoZFPceXH/938Kr0atTCtL1GNublaFR@6c/aIIuTfR67klccthqSU1FjgVyVpHXsqrTGMILIQUgjir1C4XCQWV903WbHjiRv7gJMCzHYAmlvUhjZAEaDCVprp/N6C0hml35Ub@7Zo7/dq8fplYk1Xrhsdl9yqx7552/gHw) if you don't mind `array` output.

Comment: hmm actually you can't use the dot product because of the empty array in `xxx` so it's 68 bytes by using the change in indexing `a` to generate `y`.

Comment: @Giuseppe: modified, thanks :)

Comment: @Giuseppe: I ask your opinion you since you're a wiser code-golfer... from comments it seems we can use a vector of characters, in this case 61 bytes are possible : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tdLfCoIwFAbwe5/CCJkTqznJMvBJxAudE4TU8E/Mp7evlPDCm7IGv5sd@HY4Z/WQBUPWlaLNq9JUdh/EzT6tuuQqTRUqIy8NdvEjSpuuMIXZhzsnsvvQiajVGwa3OB0y3JOa2OQIEjyowIdisoEDuHACBmdI4Q6CUKpvdaluUrQy1V2uvXIVaiPUvz2zXDbGOmviFmKnbvmPY9/d2iQGDsk0RPHpU7NYb4z9RbML3bL/DOH5m1avbb4ypmnDAw "R – Try It Online") what do you think ?

Comment: use `strtoi` instead of `as.double`, but yeah, that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
fØDV€1ịṭƊ+_Ḃ?ƝS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//ZsOYRFbigqwx4buL4bmtxoorX@G4gj/GnVP///9yNWU2bzltbSEvMzcwOGR2Yw)

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I borrow `1ịṭƊ`

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>85</strike> <strike>84</strike> <strike>83</strike> 82 bytes

-1 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)

```javascript
s=>(s.match(/\d/g)||[]).reduce((r,n,i,a)=>r+(+n)+a[a[++i]!=null?i:0]*-(1-n%2*2),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcrLEoIgFIDhfW/hovEcwUs13Qd7EHPBABoNQgPqynenaW/b7//ffOZBeP0Zc@ukih2LgdUQioGP4gXlU5Y9LkvTYuGVnIQC8NRSTTmy2hMgFglveEOIbhNmJ2Me@la1WQ673G732R5phVE4G5xRhXE9dJD6ozq56zAk5eFcXeQsUsT75t@0Hlf1h/EL)

Takes the string input, finds the digits as an array of characters or returns empty array if none found, and then uses type coercion to ensure the values are added/subtracted correctly. The forward lookup preincrements the index and uses a null check for brevity, and then the final part checks whether number is odd or even to then force addition or subtraction ( + and - is -, etc)

Comment: `n-0` can be `+n`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <s>77</s> 69 bytes

```julia
s->(s=s.-'0';s=s[0.<=s.<=9];endof(s)>0?sum(2(s%2).*[s[2:end];s[]]):0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzZCsIwFETf/YoYkN5IG9PUVrv6ISEPtQtUutFrRb8@VlF0YGAOB@Yyt00emJqkxKCTAabIHUtY8TKU4MmCSRrquOrLoQZkmTjh3IEE3EjGtwqVjBanY1Ras0gw0@UjLE/j1PTXtocaFHLONWM2gRV5h05@FQxh16133kEcy1tB7a9ypbf3f5hj/Qfnwr0/qE3oq4La1KUfx5h5Ag)

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 48 bytes

```perl
$;=$;[++$-%@;],$\+=$_%2?$_+$;:$_-$;for@;=/\d/g}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/F2lbFOlpbW0VX1cE6VkclRttWJV7VyF4lXlvF2kolXlfFOi2/yMHaVj8mRT@9tvr//yLTVLN8y9xcRX1jcwOLlLLkf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

I quite like how cryptic this looks, but it's a pretty straightforward loop around all the numbers in the string.

Answer (score 0):

#### C Sharp 180 bytes

This isn't very good golfing, lol.

```
s=>{var q=new Queue<int>(s.Where(Char.IsNumber).Select(n=>n-48));q.Enqueue(q.First());int t,o=0;o=q.Dequeue();try{while(true){t+=o+(o%2==0?-1:1)*(o=q.Dequeue());}}catch{return t;}}
```

Ungolfed :

```
var q = new Queue<int>(s.Where(Char.IsNumber).Select(n=>n-48));
int t,o=0;

q.Enqueue(q.First());    
o=q.Dequeue();

try{
    while(true){
        t += o + (o%2==0?-1:1) * (o=q.Dequeue());
    }
}
catch {
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÿ←«4é■≥B▬ê→█T♥
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=981bae3482fef24216881adb5403&i=r5e6o9mm%21%2F3708dvc&a=1)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
Vd|&    filter out non-digits
c|(\    zip into pairs after rotating right
F       for each digit pair
  B2%s  first-of-pair % 2, then swap top two stack elements
  eH*   eval digit as integer, double, then multiply
  +     add to running total
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=Vd%7C%26++%09filter+out+non-digits%0Ac%7C%28%5C++%09zip+into+pairs+after+rotating+right%0AF+++++%09for+each+digit+pair%0A++B2%25s%09first-of-pair+%25+2,+then+swap+top+two+stack+elements%0A++eH*+%09eval+digit+as+integer,+double,+then+multiply%0A++%2B+++%09add+to+running+total&i=r5e6o9mm%21%2F3708dvc&a=1)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```
s=>s.filter(t=>1/t&&~(a+=u*t,u=t%2),a=u=0)[0]*u+a<<1
```

Expects input as an array of characters.
Caveat: Due to use of bit-shifting, the output has an upper bound of `2^31-1`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZchLCoMwFEDReVeRDmoSjX/sB3zZSCk0aCyWaMS8OOzW04HQSSf3wnmrTbluHRdMZ9vrMEBwIF02jAb1yhBkmWMUfZhKwMcoPOCp4kKBh4Lfi0fsE9W2ZUACxBGQpLOzs0Znxr6YE4SmkgoyMJe5xYz4fHJ@QEbXRp/tbZqOeX0prv3W0X9ufry33ldRHr4)

## Explanation

Essentially doubles the sum of the digits following odd values.

```
s => s.filter(             // filter to preserve the first digit
    t =>
        1/t &&             // short-circuits if NaN
        ~(                 // coerce to truthy value
            a += u * t,    // adds value only if previous digit is odd
            u = t%2        // store parity of current digit
        ),
    a = u = 0
)[0]                       // first digit
* u + a
<< 1                       // bit-shift to multiply by 2 (also coerces a NaN resulting from a string devoid of digits to 0)
```